# Help with SQL query, should I use Pivot

Tags: pivot

I have a table that returns data like

| ID | Code | Error | Date | VB1 | VB2 | VB3 | VB4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | E1 | Uncap Error | 2021-02-25 | 8 | 0 | 0 | 9 |
| 3 | E1.2 | Recap Error | 2021-02-25 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 6 |
| 4 | E2 | Recap Error | 2021-02-26 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | E3 | Tip failure | 2021-02-25 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | E4 | Tip failure | 2021-02-26 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

But I need to get it to look like

| ID | Code | Error | 2021-02-25 VB1 | 2021-02-25 VB2 | 2021-02-25 VB3 | 2021-02-25 VB4 | 2021-02-26 VB1 | 2021-02-26 VB2 | 2021-02-26 VB3 | 2021-02-26 VB4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | E1 | Uncap Error | 8 | 0 | 0 | 9 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | E1.2 | Recap Error | 3 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 6 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 5 | E3 | Tip failure | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

So looking to pivot on the date but also on each VB#,I can get to work with one VB# but not a range

Please advise

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum! Why are 4 and 6 not eliminated? What server are you using? Please construct a fiddle (dbfiddle.uk) for your table and data.

Comment: That looks like it should be done in the reporting layer.  Otherwise it's going to require dynamic SQL to get a pivot to work for you.

Comment: @JonathanFite It can be accomplished without Dynamic SQL (assuming we're all talking SQL Server here, since OP didn't actually tag a database system yet), but if it's reasonably accomplishable without Dynamic SQL will be dependent on how unique his `Date` column is, which likely is a different story, lol.